# sum (adding 2 numbers ) without plus operator

Tags: c

Can anyone explain the logic how to add `a` and `b`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int a=30000, b=20, sum;
     char *p;
     p = (char *) a;
     sum = (int)&p[b];  //adding a and b!
     printf("%d",sum);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use the `+` operator already. Don't write crazy code like this. Everybody will hate you.

Comment: To expand on Raymond's remark: if you were asked this at a job interview and `(int)&p[b]` was considered a correct answer, working there looks like a bad choice for the long term. If you found this jewel in an old book, look for another book. Recent compilers do not treat pointer arithmetic as blindly as they used to (http://lwn.net/Articles/278137/ ). Your program may cease to work with any new compiler version.

Comment: I think all these tricks are not meant not be used, their purpose is to understand how C works and for some of them to understand the dark corners of C.

Comment: @ouah Precisely. Modern C does not work this way. Testing with current compilers may only give you the impression that it does. A few years down the line the OP may find him/herself complaining that pointer arithmetic does not work like it used to, that signed arithmetic overflow does not work like it used to, or that uninitialized variables do not work like they used to.

Comment: So @user1215233, next challenge for you. How to divide an unsigned integer by `4` without using the `>>` or `/` operators? Also without using any loop statement.

Comment: @ouah: Easy. `n >>= 2;` or `n /= 4;` (Those are different operators.)

Comment: On an interesting side note, this is completely equivalent to `sum = (int)&b[p];  //adding a and b!` and even `sum = (int)&20[p];` ... `a[10] == 10[a]`

Comment: Study up on adder circuits, break the values into bits, and implement adders for each bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding two numbers without using +](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244510/adding-two-numbers-without-using)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `+` is hidden here:

```
&p[b]
```

this expression is equivalent to

```
(p + b)
```

So we actually have:

```
(int) &p[b] == (int) ((char *) a)[b]) == (int) ((char *) a + b) == a + b
```

Note that this technically invokes undefined behavior as `(char *) a` has to point to an object and pointer arithmetic outside an object or one past the object invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry for meticulousness, but `&p[b]` is equivalent to `p + b` only if `sizeof(*p) == 1`

Comment: if you're addressing me, I didn't downvote you, just left comment

Comment: @Ivan I wasn't addressing you Ivan, I was addressing the downvoter.

Comment: @Ivan: That's not true. `p[b]` and `p + b` both take `sizeof(*p)` into account in performing the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @ruakh, you confuse the cases when you add pointers and get pointer as result (then `sizeof(*p)` is taken into account indeed) and when you add two numbers `p` and `b`, that was I wrote about

Comment: @Ivan: If you were writing about a case when `p` is a number, then what exactly did you mean by `sizeof(*p)`? For example, if `p` is of type `int`, then what do you think is the type of `*p`?

Comment: @ruakh, you know, all the controversy is caused by initial @ouah's statement - "&p[b]

this expression is equivalent to 
(p + b)" because the first expression is in terms of pointers, and the second is in terms of numbers stored in pointer variables. So my first remark referred to that if we add numbers stored in pointer variables, then the result is equal to `&p[b]` expression only if `sizeof(*p) == 1`. Of course when you work with pointers but not with just their values `sizeof` is taken into account automatically

Comment: @Ivan: But those expressions *are* equivalent, it's just a fact. Both expressions assume that one (presumably `p`) is a pointer and the other (presumably `b`) is an integer. Regardless of whether the value of `p` is *really* is a pointer, or just a "number[] stored in [a] pointer variable[]", `p+b` will still take `sizeof(*p)` into account, because the compiler *does not know* what the value of `p` is!

Answer (score 10):

C standard says that `E1[E2]` is equivalent to `*((E1) + (E2))`. Therefore:

```
 &p[b] = &*((p) + (b)) = ((p) + (b)) = ((a) + (b)) = a + b
```

Comment: Note that the standard also says that both `p` and `p + b` need to _"point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object [...] otherwise, the behavior is undefined."_

Comment: @moooeeeep: Of course, it is anyway a very bad idea to write code like this. I was explaining the behavior on his computer.

Answer (score 5):

`p[b]` is the *b-th* element of the array `p`. It's like writing `*(p + b)`.

Now, when adding `&` it'll be like writing: `p + b * sizeof(char)` which is `p + b`.
Now, you'll have `(int)((char *) a + b)` which is.. `a + b`.

But.. when you still have `+` in your keyboard, use it.

---

As @gerijeshchauhan clarified in the comments, `*` and `&` are inverse operations, they cancel each other. So `&*(p + b)` is `p + b`.

Comment: I feel you should add second line: `if  x is pointer then &*x == x. similarly  &*(p + b) = (p+b)`

Answer (score 3):

1. p is made a pointer to char
2. a is converted to a pointer to char, thus making p point to memory with address a
3. Then the subscript operator is used to get to an object at an offset of b beyond the address pointed to by p.  b is 20 and p+20=30020 . Then the address-of operator is used on the resulting object to convert the address back to int, and you've got the effect of a+b

The below comments might be easier to follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int a=30000, b=20, sum;
     char *p; //1. p is a pointer to char
     p = (char *) a; //2. a is converted to a pointer to char and p points to memory with address a (30000)
     sum = (int)&p[b];  //3. p[b] is the b-th (20-th) element from address of p. So the address of the result of that is equivalent to a+b
     printf("%d",sum);
     return 0;
}
```

Reference: [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/307595/char-pointer-problem)

Comment: any difference both p = (char *) a; vs p = (char *)&a;?

p = (char *) a;  //p is *a value?
p = (char *)&a;  //p is memory address of a ?

Comment: yah ur pretty much right, p = (char *)a...will result in p pointing to memory with address 3000 while p = (char *)&a...will result in p pointing to memory with the address of a

Answer (score 2):

```
char *p;
```

`p` is a pointer (to element with size 1 byte)

---

```
p=(char *)a;
```

now `p` points to memory with address `a`

---

```
sum= (int)&p[b];
```

`p` pointer can be use as array `p[]` (start address (in memory) of this array is `a`)

`p[b]` means to get *b-th* element - this element address is `a+b`

[ (start address)`a` + `b` (b-th element * size of element (1 byte)) ]

`&p[b]` means to get address of element at `p[b]` but its address is `a+b`

---

if you use pointer to int (mostly 4 bytes)

```
int* p
p = (int*)a;
```

your sum will be  **a+(4*b)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 int a=30000, b=20, sum;
 char *p; //1. p is a pointer to char
 p = (char *) a;
```

`a` is of type `int`, and has the value `30000`.  The above assignment converts the value `30000` from `int` to `char*` and stores the result in `p`.

The semantics of converting integers to pointers are (partially) defined by the C standard. Quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft, section 6.3.2.3 paragraph 5:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.

with a (non-normative) footnote:

> The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an
>   integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing
>   structure of the execution environment.

The standard makes no guarantees about the relative sizes of types `int` and `char*`; either could be bigger than the other, and the conversion could lose information. The result of this particular conversions is very unlikely to be a valid pointer value. If it's a trap representation, then the behavior of the assignment is undefined.

On a typical system you're likely to be using, `char*` is at least as big as `int`, and integer-to-pointer conversions *probably* just reinterpret the bits making up the integer's representation as the representation of a pointer value.

```
 sum = (int)&p[b];
```

`p[b]` is by definition equivalent to `*(p+b)`, where the `+` denotes pointer arithmetic. Since the pointer points to `char`, and a `char` is by definition 1 byte, the addition advances the pointed-to address by `b` bytes in memory (in this case 20).

But `p` is probably not a valid pointer, so any attempt to perform arithmetic on it, or even to access its value, has undefined behavior.

In practice, most C compilers generate code that doesn't perform extra checks. The emphasis is on fast execution of correct code, not on detection of incorrect code. So *if* the previous assignment to `p` set it to an address corresponding to the number `30000`, then adding `b`, or 20, to that address will probably yield an address corresponding to the number `30020`.

That address is the result of `(p+b)`; now the `[]` operator implicitly applies the `*` operator to that address, giving you the object that that address points to -- conceptually, this is a `char` object stored at an address corresponding to the integer `30020`.

We immediately apply the `&` operator to that object. There's a special-case rule that says applying `&` to the result of a `[]` operator is equivalent to just doing the pointer addition; see 6.5.3.2p2 in the above referenced standard draft.

So this:

```
&p[b]
```

is equivalent to:

```
p + b
```

which, as I said above, yields an address (of type `char*`) corresponding to the integer value `30020` -- assuming, of course, that integer-to-pointer conversions behave in a certain way and that the undefined behavior of constructing and accessing an invalid pointer value don't do anything surprising.

Finally, we use a cast operator to convert this address to type `int`. Conversion of a pointer value to an integer is also implementation-defined, and possibly undefined. Quoting 6.3.2.3p6:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

It's not uncommon for a `char*` to be bigger than an `int` (for example, I'm typing this on a system with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `char*`). But we're relatively safe from overflow in this case, because the `char*` value is the result of converting an in-range `int` value. there's no guarantee that converting a given value from `int` to `char*` and back to `int` will yield the original result, but it commonly works that way, at least for values that are in range.

So *if* a number of implementation-specific assumptions happen to be satisfied by the implementation on which the code happens to be running, then this code is likely to yield the same result as `30000 + 20`.

Incidentally, I've worked on a system where this would have failed. The Cray T90 was a word-addressed machine, with hardware addresses pointing to 64-bit words; there was no hardware support for byte addressing. But `char` was 8 bits, so `char*` and `void*` pointers had to be constructed and manipulated in hardware. A `char*` pointer consisted of a 64-bit word pointer with a byte offset stored in the otherwise unused high-order 3 bits. Conversions between pointers and integers did not treat these high-order bits specially; they were simply copied. So `ptr + 1` and `(char*)(int)ptr + 1)` could yield very different results.

But hey, you've managed to add two small integers without using the `+` operator, so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the pointer arithmetic is to use bitops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned addtwo(unsigned one, unsigned two);

unsigned addtwo(unsigned one, unsigned two)
{
unsigned carry;

for( ;two; two = carry << 1)    { 
        carry = one & two; 
        one ^= two;
        } 
return one;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned one, two, result;

if ( sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &one ) < 1) return 0;
if ( sscanf(argv[2], "%u", &two ) < 1) return 0;

result = addtwo(one, two);

fprintf(stdout, "One:=%u Two=%u Result=%u\n", one, two, result );

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a completely different note, perhaps what was being looked for was an understanding of how binary addition is done in hardware, with XOR, AND, and bit shifting. In other words, an algorithm something like this:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{ int partial_sum = a ^ b;
  int carries = a & b;

  if (carries)
    return add(partial_sum, carries << 1);
  else
    return partial_sum;
}
```

Or an iterative equivalent (although, gcc, at least, recognizes the leaf function and optimizes the recursion into an iterative version anyway; probably other compilers would as well)....

Probably needs a little more study for the negative cases, but this at least works for positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
by sch.

001010101 = 85
001000111 = 71
---------
010011100 = 156
*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define SET_N_BIT(i,sum) ((1 << (i)) | (sum))

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    int t = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int ia = 0, ib = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int mask = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8; i++)
    {   
        mask = 1 << i;
        ia = a & mask;
        ib = b & mask;

        if(ia & ib)
            if(t)
            {
                sum = SET_N_BIT(i,sum);
                t = 1;
                /*i(1) t=1*/
            }
            else
            {
                t = 1;
                /*i(0) t=1*/
            }
        else if (ia | ib)
            if(t)
            {
                t = 1;
                /*i(0) t=1*/
            }
            else
            {
                sum = SET_N_BIT(i,sum);
                t = 0;
                /*i(1) t=0*/
            }
        else
            if(t)
            {
                sum = SET_N_BIT(i,sum);
                t = 0;
                /*i(1) t=0*/
            }
            else
            {
                t = 0;
                /*i(0) t=0*/
            }

    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 85;
    int b = 71;
    int i = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

        printf("%d: %d + %d = %d\n", ++i, a, b, sum(a, b));
    }

    return 0;
}
```